# How can I copy all the objects from temporary object to another object

Tags: c++

How can I copy all the objects to another set of objects. I created a temporary object so I can add the current "robot" to the "robotSquad". I am trying to dynamically add it

I am new to the concept of operator overloading, I might have the wrong assumption on what I'm doing. Im using the += operator, making a temp if there is no space in "robotSquad" adding it to temp then copying it to the original robotSquad named r_robot. 
I could possibly be doing all this wrong, need help Thanks!

```
  RobotSquad& RobotSquad::operator+=(const Robot& p_robot) {

    if (count <= sizeof(r_robots)) {

        //how do i copy?
        RobotSquad temp[count+1];
        temp[count]=p_robot;
        for(int i=0 ;i<=sizeof(r_robots);i++){
            temp[i]=r_robots[i];
        }
    } else {
         this ->r_robots[count]=p_robot;
    }

    count++;
    return *this;
}


class RobotSquad {

    char* name ;
    Robot *r_robots;
    int count;

public:

    //constructor
    RobotSquad();
    RobotSquad(Robot* , int, char* p_name= "No name");
    ~RobotSquad();

    //getters
    char* getName();
    Robot* getRoster();
    int getCount();

    //setters
    char setName();
    Robot setRobot();
    int setCount();

    //other
    RobotSquad& operator+=(const Robot&);

private:
    void setEmpty();
};
```

Comment: If you don't *need* to use the += operator you can define RobotSquad as a vector of Robots and just push_back() the Robot.

Comment: im supposed to use the += operator

Comment: You could implement this `push_back()` inside your overloaded operator and have a data member that is `std::vector<Robots>` as @Roy2511 suggested

Comment: Can you show the `RobotSquad` class declaration?

Comment: @ignacio I'll not give you the answer because this seems like a homework problem. But, look into [realloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)

Comment: `sizeof(r_robots)` is the same as `sizeof(Robot*)`. It is either 4 or 8, depending on your platform. It does not tell you how many robots you have allocated; you need to keep track of that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

With std, it could be:

```
class RobotSquad {
    std::vector<Robot> robots;
    std::string name;

public:

    //constructor
    RobotSquad() = default;
    explicit RobotSquad(const std::vector<Robot>& robots,
                        const std::string& name= "No name")
        : robots{robots}, name{name}
    {}
    ~RobotSquad() = default;

    RobotSquad& operator+=(const Robot& robot)
    {
        robots.push_back(robot);
        return *this;
    }

    // ...
};
```